# How do I retrieve the mimeData for a particular item in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am trying to programmatically "drop" an item onto a `QTableWidget` using `QTableWidget::dropMimeData().`

I know which item I want to drop and I know that `QTreeWidget` has a `QTreeWidget::mimeData()` function, but I can not use that `mimeData()` function because it is protected.

Basically, how can I "select" a QTreeWidgetItem, pack up its mimeData, and "drop" that item onto a QTableWidget programmatically (no actual mouse drag/drop)?

Thank you.

---

As far as actual code:

Lets say I have a QTreeWidget with 3 "levels"

```
   QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui->treeWidget->child(i)->child(j)->child(k);
```

gets me my QTreeWidgetItem.

Now lets say I want to drop `item` onto my QTableWidget programmatically.

I need to use `QTableWidget::dropMimeData(row,col,mimeData,action)` *(right?)*

So how do I obtain the mimeData from `item` (that would be auto packed from a normal drag) so I can place it into the function call for `dropMimeData` ?

Comment: I can't help you because I don't know what your code is. What's in your hands and how do you want the final state?

Comment: See the new section at the bottom of my question. There isn't much code actually written for this part of the program. I have tried a few different mothods but the closest I found was the mimeData function from QTreeWidget (which is protected, so I can't access/use it from my class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use `QTableWidget::dropMimeData(row,col,mimeData,action)` because it's protected.

In my opinion, you can use `QVariant QTreeWidgetItem::data(int column, int role) const` to get your tree node. After that, you could use `QTableWidget::setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem *item)` to insert a new item.

This is an example from [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#details) to show how to insert a new row into the table:

```
QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(
        (row+1)*(column+1)));
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
```

Comment: Copying data to a ```QTableWidgetItem``` from the ```QTreeWidgetItem``` and then manually adding that item to the ```QTableWidget``` was how I did it in the end. I still think there should be a way of retrieving the mimeData from an item though. Why not provide a ```getMimeData``` function for ease of use? Oh well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that is in the drop event

```
 void MyWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent* e)
 {
      const QMimeData* mimeData = e->mimeData();
      ...
```